# Input from bluetooth output to iPhone native Jack ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-audio, avaudiosession, avaudiosessiondelegate

I am working on an application. the scope of the application is  to take input audio via Bluetooth microphone and output audio should go to the iPhone Native Jack. I was working with `AVAudioSesion` class Using Following code:-

```
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput, sizeof (allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);
```

When i use this code this code route the input via `Bluetooth` but at same time it also route the output also to the same Bluetooth device. I just want a solution for this problem. You can suggest any third party library also. Or if Any New API introduced by Apple with `iOS 8` then it will also work.

Comment: Is that really related to CoreBluetooth (that is only for BLE), since BLE isn't suited for Audio?

Comment: @larme Sorry for misunderstanding. But In question i Didn't mentioned anything about core Bluetooth. Actually we are using Classic Bluetooth in microphone for taking Input. Any way i Just need help on this matter.

Comment: Indeed, but since you tagged it with "CoreBluetooth" that is the Apple's framework for BLE... That was confusing.

Comment: @larme So you have any solution for this problem?